# Unable binding thumbnail of youtube video

Tags: wpf, windows, windows-phone-8, youtube-api, windows-store-apps

I could not load images of thumbnail youtube.

Class file:

```
public class YoutubeVideo
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public DateTime pubdate { get; set; }
    public Uri youtubelink { get; set; }
    public Uri videolink { get; set; }
    public Uri thumbnail { get; set; }

}
```

On mainpage.xaml:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="{Binding thumbnail}"></Image>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" FontSize="10" Foreground="#cc181e" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
        <Grid>

        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

It just show title.

Comment: please clearing if the question about binding the thumbnail or loading the thumbnail?

Comment: SyndicationFeed feed = await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(youtubeuri);

                List<DataModel.YoutubeVideo> i = new List<DataModel.YoutubeVideo>();
                DataModel.YoutubeVideo video;
video.thumbnail = new Uri("http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + video.id + "/default.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
                    i.Add(video);

Comment: to me it seems like authentication issue. you may perhaps download the image separately and load the downloaded version. is it possible for you to post a working sample of your application?

Comment: Ok. That link :http://www.mediafire.com/download/ib6azxwk25qdy0b/YoutubeStore.zip
Or you give me the email

Comment: this is not a valid link to the file. do share the file and provide the sharing link.

Comment: I must where do i upload?

Comment: your problem is with this line `video.id = item.Id.Remove(0, 27);` as I can't execute the code here could you tell me the value of `item.Id` or `item.guid`? Then I'll be able to answer for the issue.

Comment: tôi có kiểm tra mã này: Ở đây:http://img.youtube.com/vi/eds/base/videos/_OBlgSz8sSM/default.jpg
my result video id is:eds/base/videos/_OBlgSz8sSM

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code here is the solution

change

```
video.id = item.Id.Remove(0, 27);
```

to

```
video.id = item.Id.Substring(item.Id.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

that should produce the correct id of the video

the id of the video is the last few chars

eg

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/videos/_OBlgSz8sSM
```

Comment: Great! you may accept this as an answer. happy coding :)

Comment: Yes, im nood about programming.But so funny.
So Do you know load sum view pages and who people has uploaded this video on youtube api;